# Find Replace Exact String Match Only

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use find/replace to identify and change only exact string matches.  For example, I want to change all references to column "AN" but I don't want the change to alter any portion of the formula that includes the condition "AND." The option tab in the dialogue box isn't providing a fix.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `AND` with `ZZZ` for instance, then replace `AN` with the desired column ID, then replace `ZZZ` back to `AND` in your formula.